# cargo build-sbf won't work?

Tags: solana-cli, build-sbf

Recently, I was trying to build the `spl-governance` program locally, but since I had `solana v1.10.39`, it seemed to fail since it didn't support `cargo build-sbf` (`build-bpf` is deprecated)

I then updated my Solana CLI using the command, `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.2/install)"` as mentioned in the docs. After this, `cargo build-sbf` started running but it timed out (possibly because of not-so-great hotel internet).

But since then, I'm unable to run `cargo build-sbf` as it gives out the following error,

```
error: not a directory: '/Users/sayantank/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.14.2/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/sbf-tools/rust/lib'
```

On digging deeper, I noticed two things,

- the directory, `.../sbf-tools`, mentioned above has a `tmp-solana-sbf-tools-osx.tar.bz2` file which I'm unable to extract.
- the directory, `.../.local/share/solana/install` has 2 directories, `releases` and `active-releases` BUT `active-releases` seems to be empty. I'm not sure if it's meant to be like that but just pointing it out.

Edit:
The command `solana-install info` gives the following output,

```
Configuration: /Users/sayantank/.config/solana/install/config.yml
Active release directory: /Users/sayantank/.local/share/solana/install/active_release
• Release version: 1.14.2
• Release URL: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/download/v1.14.2/solana-release-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2
• Release commit: 25ce9a7
Install is up to date. 1.14.2 is the latest compatible release
```

Edit:
I just tried running `cargo build-bpf` and it gives the following output,

```
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/sayantank/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
```

and then goes on to compile, does it mean its using the `build-sbf` in the background? `cargo build-sbf` still fails with the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after a couple of days of head-banging, finally figured out where the cache for my failed installation was being stored.

The issue would be solved if you clear your `$HOME/.cache/solana`.

Answer (score 1):

use `cargo-build-sbf` insted of `cargo build-sbf` it should work