anchor build not working for my project
error: not a directory: '/Users/macbook/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.18.18/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/bin'
The error above is what i get when i run anchor build.
Using macOs, i have uninstalled and installed both solana and anchor, still no solution

I know this is a lightly different question, but when two questions have the same cause and answer (anchor build runs build-sbf) the policy is to mark them as duplicate.

Could you try clearing your $HOME/.cache/solana as suggested by this answer https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/3378/1708
